# Change CGSize with a variable

Tags: swift, core-graphics, skaction

I want to change the size of my SKNode with a variable so it can be made smaller with a for loop. It is giving me an error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'CGSize' that accepts an argument list of type '(width:... , height:...)'

```
for (var i = 0.9; i > 0.0; i -= 0.1){
           for (var k = 1.25; i > 0.0; i -= 0.1){

                self.sun.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width * i, height: self.size.height * k) // error here
        } 
}
```

Comment: that's an infinite loop, and you should use `for` loops like that anyway... and it doesn't even make sense since you're shadowing away your loop variables anyway....

Comment: The problem is probably to do with you trying to multiply `CGFloat` and `Double`. Also, since you're using Sprite Kit you can use `SKAction`s to change the size of a node.

Comment: Edited for loop to make sense. I will try SKAction and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this SKAction code instead of a for loop suggested by ABakerSmith and it looks a lot cleaner.

```
var shrinkSun = SKAction.scaleBy(0.5, duration: 2)
self.sun.runAction(shrinkSun)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because `self.size.width` is `CGFloat` and `i` is `Double` (same with `self.size.height` and `k`). `CGFloat` cannot be multiplied by a `Double`. Try the code below.

```
for (var i = CGFloat(0.9); i > 0.0; i -= 0.1){
        for (var k = CGFloat(1.25); i > 0.0; i -= 0.1){

            self.sun.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width * i, height: self.size.height * k) // error here
        }
    }
```

I have tested it with Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0. In case something goes wrong code below will definitely work

```
for (var i = 0.9; i > 0.0; i -= 0.1){
       for (var k = 1.25; i > 0.0; i -= 0.1){

            self.sun.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width * CGFloat(i), height: self.size.height * CGFloat(k)) // error here
    } 
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly man thanks a lot. I had to adjust the size a few times because it disappears but I looks great.